# Why does `cargo new` create a binary instead of a library?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am creating a library with Rust. On library creation I type

```
cargo new name
```

According to the docs this should create a lib, because `--bin` is omitted.
However, the file is auto set to a binary.

Is there a setting I have to adjust to disable auto setting all projects to binary?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> #### Cargo features
>
> Cargo’s CLI has one really important change this release: `cargo new` will now default to generating a binary, rather than a library. We try to keep Cargo’s CLI quite stable, but this change is important, and is unlikely to cause breakage.
>
> For some background, `cargo new` accepts two flags: `--lib`, for creating libraries, and `--bin`, for creating binaries, or executables. If you don’t pass one of these flags, in previous versions of Cargo, it would default to `--lib`. We made this decision because each binary (often) depends on many libraries, and so the library case is more common. However, this is incorrect; each library is depended upon by many binaries. Furthermore, when getting started, what you often want is a program you can run and play around with. It’s not just new Rustaceans though; even very long-time community members have said that they find this default surprising. As such, we’re changing it.

[Source](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/03/29/Rust-1.25.html)

Comment: Derp. Thanks. Will mark as answered after time limit is up

Comment: Ouch -- everyone who found this surprising and had to learn the Rust way now has to unlearn that -- every piece of documentation written since then is now wrong, my Kindle ebook "Programming Rust" is wrong, and so are all the printed copies of it. Wow. Rust is not a baby language anymore, it has real users. This seems like a really strange change to make at this stage.

Comment: @FredrickBrennan I have checked and all calls in "Programming Rust" are `cargo new --bin` which is as it was, what have changed is that `cargo new` (without any flags) will now behave different. If you have been using flags always then nothing will change.

Comment: @FredrickBrennan This concern cargo not rust directly.

Answer (score 6):

Since Cargo 1.25 `cargo new` [defaults to creating a binary crate, instead of a library crate](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/5029).

> cargo new accepts two flags: --lib, for creating libraries, and --bin, for creating binaries, or executables.

See the [Changelog for 1.25](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e0a9bd0f3cfd20694ff62ac8b74747adcdbbfa99/RELEASES.md#cargo).