# When should I use the --bin option for cargo new?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

What is the difference between `cargo new <project_name> --bin` and `cargo new <project_name>`?

It seems both commands make exactly the same project; all components are consistent.

I think `--bin` stands for "binary", but I don't know when to use this option or not.

Comment: by default cargo new creates a new binary crate, so mostly is the same afaik

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference between `cargo new` and `cargo new --bin`. From [First Steps with Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/first-steps.html), emphasis mine:

> To start a new package with Cargo, use `cargo new`:
>
> ```
> $ cargo new hello_world
> ```
>
> **Cargo defaults to `--bin` to make a binary program**. To make a library, we would pass `--lib`, instead.

Likewise, Cargo's command line help tells you the same thing. From `cargo new --help`, with some irrelevant lines removed:

```
% cargo new --help
OPTIONS:
        --bin                      Use a binary (application) template [default]
        --lib                      Use a library template
```

See also

- [Why does `cargo new` create a binary instead of a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49706460/155423)
- [What is the difference between library crates and normal crates in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60266905/155423)